# Opportunity Dependent Fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I have 2 controlling fields  new_field and stage, and both have  thier own dependant fields.   When the user clicks on one of those dependancies, they want both sets of dependant fields in a single pop up, and have the fields appear in a certain order. At this point, there are 2 seperate pop-ups.

Can I do this? Any ideas?

Not sure if this will be an Apex/VF solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box. If the customer wants control over exact behavior and layout, you'll need to do something custom using JS and VF.

There is a poor-man's version of this, though. Let's say your dependent fields are F1->F2 and F3->F4.

You have defined the dependencies between F1/F2 and F3/F4 already. If you now add an additional dependency, between F1 to F3, and make it 100% filled (i.e. all values of F3 valid for all values of F1), you will get all 4 fields in the popup.

Salesforce controls the layout, and it won't be what you expect; I think in this case it would go F1, F3, F4, F2. You also won't be able to fill in a value for any of the other fields if there is no value yet filled in for F1.

It may be an OK workaround since it's easy to implement, but it's unlikely to be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any standard solution available, generally all the related/dependent picklist appear in same popup.

Seems like you have to code your own VF page using jquery/js and add a onclick event on these field to bring a popup.